# What is this user input encoded as?

Tags: character-encoding, attributes

What encoding/encryption/manipulation would turn the following values from what you see on the left to what's on the right?

- `146.00  =>   4046401A36E2EB1D`
- `36.30   =>   4042266666666666`
- `76.22   =>   40530E147AE147AE`
- `3865.20 =>   40DA06683E8C7FD4`
- `0.200   =>   3FC999999999999A`

I am working with an XML file from a software application we use at work. I am trying to set up a tool that helps interpret and manipulate the XML files outside of the software, to allow work to be done while off of the limited licenses we have. In the software, users populate fields and can import/export XML files containing the info they have entered. When I open these XML files in a text editor, all the fields are clearly labeled as they would be in the program itself. The user input data is "encoded" however (hoping that's the accurate term), and it appears to be hexadecimal.

I have been able to take string and integer inputs and convert them back and forth to what's in the XML file, although the strings are backwards (the hex decodes to "w im 9" when the user input "9 mi w"). However anything the user enters as a decimal number is giving me trouble [edit: I determined the trouble is with fields that have associated units]. Some preliminary research has brought me to the idea of "attributes", but I don't know enough of XML to make use/sense of it. Below are two lines from the XML, the first one where the user data plays nice when trying to decode, and the second where something else is happening:

`<BRIDGE_ID HEX="true">#31</BRIDGE_ID>` Here the user just entered "1" for the Bridge ID

`<LENGTH Units="23" HEX="true">#3FD381D7DBF487FD</LENGTH>` Here the user entered "1" for length and the program forced it to 1.00 before exporting. This field is in feet.

I have discovered that the fields which assign units to the values are the ones that are not reversing nicely. Any field without units, i.e. no attributes in XML, works great in a simple web decoder. So the attributes complicate it somehow. In the first 5 examples at the top, the first value is in feet (Units="23"), while the second and third fields are both degrees (Units="52").

I know this is all over the place! Thank you anyone who can make sense of it and help me out!

Answer (score 0):

For the 2nd, 3rd, and 5th values, the 16-digit hex string is simply the hex representation of the internal 64-bit double-precision IEEE floating point value whose decimal representation appears on the left.

That doesn't work for the 1st and 4th values, where the hex string is the representation of 44.50 and 26649.628817677338 respectively. Since you talk about units, perhaps there might be conversion from American units to metric involved?

This question has nothing to do with XML. Just because the data is wrapped in XML tags doesn't make it an XML question.

Comment: Thank you for your help! That makes more sense now.

Sorry I tagged the post wrong. I didn't realize the XML part didn't matter. I'm very unfamiliar with all of this.